# Find Deprecated releases of all the azure resources for java sdk using python script or any other script

Tags: deprecated, azure-java-sdk, azure-releases

I have a specific use case in which I want to block all the pipelines in cicd in `Azure DevOps` which are using the resources of the deprecated releases or who have them in their pom.xml file

I tried parsing the XML file and finding the version using pattern but not able to find the way using script.